# MySQL - Table with BLOBs on same DB

Tags: sql, mysql

Does having another table on my DB with lots of BLOBs affect the performance of queries on the rest of the tables within that same DB?

Another very related question, roughly how much will it affect the other tables queries **while** i'm querying the blobs table?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BLOBS are stored separately from the database table (e.g. in separate filesystem objects), so the total size of the blobs won't affect querying that table or the other tables in your database.

If you are querying the blobs table while querying other tables in your database, it still shouldn't have any more of an impact than if it were  a regular table because again, the BLOBS are stored separately. The things that will impact your query are its complexity and your index structure.

If you are doing lots of reads of blobs in the blobs table this will generate a lot of disk activity, which could slow down other disk activity that the database server generates -- but if your indices are kept in memory it won't slow down the querying.